# How to change Tab Bar Background color and Tab Bar Item color on Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am a new learner. I have created a new storyboard with tabbar controller. I want to change the background color, item color and text color. I search through but I found only changing color with coding. What are the necessary steps to customize those if I am using story board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look for this image if it could help u

[image]

I have changed the color of tabbar to 'group table view background color'. There are other options that can help u to edit item color & text color.

DONT FORGET TO SELECT THE ITEM OF WHICH U WANT TO CHANGE THE PROPERTIES